# Are the quaternions Morita equivalent to the real numbers?

Tags: ring-theory, category-theory, modules, morita-equivalence

I'm wondering whether the quaternions are Morita equivalent to the real numbers. The characterisation in terms of full idempotents seems unwieldly. I can use the category-theoretic definition, but it appears for obvious choices of functors $F : {}_{\mathbb R}M \to {}_{\mathbb H}M$ (via ring extension) and $G : {}_{\mathbb H}M \to {}_{\mathbb R}M$ (via ring restriction), there cannot be an isomorphism between $F \circ G(V)$ and $V$ for any fixed vector space $V$, as $\dim(F \circ G(V)) = 4\dim(V)$. I'm thinking the answer is no.

Comment: You might be interested in the [Brauer group of a CSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brauer_group).  While $\mathbb H$ isn't morita equivalent to $\mathbb R$, the algebra $\mathbb H\otimes_\mathbb R\mathbb H$ _is_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $F$ is a field, then the only rings Morita equivalent to $F$ are the matrix rings $M_n(F)$ for positive integer $n$. In particular, since $\mathbb{H}\not\cong M_n(\mathbb{R})$ for any positive integer $n$, $\mathbb{H}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are not Morita equivalent.

Why is this true? It's a well-known characterization that $R$ is Morita equivalent to $S$ if and only if $R\cong \mathrm{End}(P)$ for some progenerator (finitely generated projective generator) $P$ in the category of $S$-modules.

If $F$ is a field, then every $F$-module is free, hence projective. And a finitely generated free $F$-module (i.e. finite dimensional $F$-vector space) is a generator if and only if its dimension is a positive integer. So $R$ is Morita equivalent to $F$ if and only if $R\cong \mathrm{End}(F^n) = M_n(F)$ for some positive integer $n$.

Comment: I would have said the same thing... but I still really wonder how hard it is to name a feature of the category of $\mathbb H$ modules distinguishing it from the category of $\mathbb R$!  Being all vector spaces, I'm at a loss to see what the inequivalence tells us about these two categories.

Comment: The fact that $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb H$ are inequivalent, but that $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb H\otimes_\mathbb R\mathbb H$ _are_ equivalent makes things even more strange.

Comment: @rschwieb Well, the category of H-modules includes one (H itself) whose endomorphism ring is isomorphic to H, and the category of R-modules does not!

Comment: I suppose that would suffice. Along those lines, (I think?) we can say that is an example of a monoid object in one of the categories that does not exist in the monoid objects of the other, to try to root it in just objects and arrows.  Very interesting...

Comment: @rschwieb More concretely, each category has exactly one object $X$ up to isomorphism with no proper non-zero subobject. In one category, any two arrows $X\to X$ commute. In the other category, this is not the case.